# Create schema and add tables to it using queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, schema, sql-grant

I created a user in my DB and now I want to give that user a schema. My question is how do I build a query that will add 30 tables to that schema ?

I know how to creat a schema and give select permision to a user on that schema, but I have no idea how to give that schema the tables I want.

FYI : I use sql server 2010 and i  want to build a query that does this, not via UI from SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ALTER SCHEMA statement to transfer object from one schema to another:

```
ALTER SCHEMA new_schema TRANSFER old_schema.table
```

For example, to construct the query to move all tables from Sales schema to new_schema (AdventureWorks2012), use this:

```
select 'ALTER SCHEMA new_schema TRANSFER Sales.' + o.name + ';'
from sys.objects o
inner join sys.schemas s on o.schema_id = s.schema_id
where s.name = 'Sales'
and o.type = 'U'
```

Comment: But my tabels are not in any schemas, there is no way I can add tables to the schema when I'm creating it?

Comment: You can't create a database object (table, view, procedure..) without it being in a schema, at least in `dbo` schema.

Comment: If you want to create a table in specific schema, use `CREATE TABLE new_schema.Table`

Comment: thank you I didn't know that. So if all my tables belong to dbo schema I will move them with ALTER SCHEMA

Comment: To be precise, all tables belong to default schema of the creator, unless otherwise specified. It is the `dbo` schema most likely.